# Obtener el nombre de un marca y mostrarlo en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy usando el plugin Perfect WooCommerce Brands para gestión de marcas de la tienda online de mi empresa.

Me gustaría obtener el nombre de la marca y convertirlo en el enlace correspondiente.

```
<?php $brands = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'pwb-brand' );
                    foreach( $brands as $brand ) { 
                            $post_excerpt = $brand->name . ' '; ?>
                            <div class="tag-brands" style="color: #fe7418 !important;font-weight: 900;font-size: 15px;">
                                    <?php echo ''.$brands;  ?>
                            </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

El resultado que obtengo es "Array" que entiendo que es el bloque completo de marcas, lo que quiero hacer es tomar la marca correspondiente a ese producto y mostrarla como un enlace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Has probado realmente a imprimir el array para ver lo que devuelve?, por que no ibas mal encaminado:

```
<?php 
$brands = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'pwb-brand' );

foreach($brands as $brand){
    echo '<div class="tag-brands" style="color: #fe7418 !important;font-weight: 900;font-size: 15px;">' . $brand->name . '</div>';
} 
?>
```

Lo único que he realizado sobre tu código ha sido retirar esta porción (donde recogías correctamente el nombre pero luego no lo imprimías:

```
$post_excerpt = $brand->name . ' ';
```

Después, en el echo que hacías simplemente he retirado la S de brandS, ya que en el foreach el valor que debes recoger es el que devuelve cada loop (brand).

Por lo demás te he limpiado un poco el código y poco más...

Saludos,

Comment: Muchísimas gracias jonilgz ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo resolví, así...

```
            <?php 
                $brands = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'pwb-brand' );
                $product_brands = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'pwb-brand');

                        $slug = 'brand'; //default

                            if ( ! empty( $product_brands ) ) {
                             if ( ! is_wp_error( $product_brands ) ) {
                                     foreach( $product_brands as $brand ) {
                                    $slug = $brand->slug;
                                                                          }
                                                                     }
                                                            }


                foreach($brands as $brand){
                echo '<div class="tag-brands" style="color: #fe7418 !important;font-weight: 900;font-size: 15px;"><a href="/brands/'. $slug .'">' . $brand->name . '</a></div>';
                } 
            ?>
```